# How to correctly bind a form element to newly created oData Entity in SAPUI5?

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I have implemented an oData Service into my SAPUI5 application.

On pressing a button the oData Model `createEntry()` is triggered which returns a Context with the newly created entity.

As per the SAPUI5 documentation - [Documentation (Creating Entities)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html#loio6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2) it should be enough to call `setBindingContext(oContext)` on my form to bind my new entity to my form.

But no matter how I try, I can't seem to get the binding working. The input fields remain empty (although the entity has set properties).

Do I need to keep a special syntax in mind when trying to do this kind of binding with an oData Model?

My form:

```
<f:SimpleForm id="form" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" title="Address" labelSpanXL="3" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3"
    labelSpanS="12" adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="4" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1"
    singleContainerFullSize="false">
    <f:content>
        <Label text="Recno"/>
        <sf:SmartField id="recno" value="{recno}"/>
    </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

My method that opens my dialog containing the form:

```
openCreateDialog: function() {
  this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("oDataModel").refreshSecurityToken(function() {
    var oContext = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("oDataModel").createEntry("/head", {
      properties: {
        recno: "100"
      }
    });
    this.byId("form").setBindingContext(oContext);
  }.bind(this), function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }, true);
  this.byId("CreateHeadDialog").open();
},
```

**EDIT**

I already tried {oDataModel>xxx} but this doesnt work. 
On the other hand, after I made my oDataModel a nameless model it seems to work fine. The smartfield correctly shows the right value, but changes I make in the UI are not applied to the property my smartfield is bound to.

When I submit pending changes of my oDataModel, all properties of my entity remain undefined, although I filled the smartfields with correct values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't my smart controls display any data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69668624/why-dont-my-smart-controls-display-any-data)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a named model: your model name is "`oDataModel`" evidenced by this in your code:

```
.getModel("oDataModel")
```

When using binding syntax in your XML View you need to prefix the field with the named model name as below:

```
<sf:SmartField id="recno" value="{oDataModel>(your-path-to-object)recno}"/>
```

If it's not in a list then you would need to reference the field as below (or navigate according to the position of recno in your json hierarchy:

```
 <sf:SmartField id="recno" value="{oDataModel>/recno}"/>
```

Comment: I don't think it needs the `/` on a binding context. `{oDataModel>recno}` should do it no?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried {oDataModel>xxx} but this doesnt work. On the other hand, after I made my oDataModel a nameless model it seems to work fine.
The smartfield correctly show the right value, but changes I make in the UI are not applied to the property my smartfield is bound to.

Comment: If changing to a nameless model solved your problem then the issue was with the way you articulated the path to your data in your binding statement. You can (and should in my view) revert to a named model and understand your path issue - this will be valuable to you in the future. Typically, in your scenario, it will be the difference beween a slash "/" and no slash after the model name (given the change from named to un-named works)